# Compile scss file at runtime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sass

I am developing a rails application that gets quite big and compiling the whole scss after every change takes longer than I want.

I thought if there was a way to dynamically compile scss file just for the portion of the site I am building that will be much faster. And I can get the compiled result as string and output to the head.

Is there a way to do it? Such as:

```
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <%= compile_scss('new_page.scss') %>
    </style>
</head>
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long is it taking?

Comment: I just counted. 10 seconds! I am using compass with many sprites as well

Answer (score 0):

You could watch the directory containing the sass files, and have them compiled whenever they change.

```
sass --watch scss:stylesheets
```

But this kind thing will only work if you have asset-pipeline disabled. Rails 3.1 and onwards, the sass compilation is done as a part of asset processing, which happens on every request in dev mode.

Answer (score 0):

Currently what i do is turn off precompiling, and use the @import in my main css files, an example stylesheets folder and files inside.

```
-stylesheets
--page1.css.scss
--page2.css.scss
--_stuff-for-page1.scss
--_stuff-for-page2.scss
```

page1.css.scss:

```
@import "stuff-for-page1";
```

page2.css.scss:

```
@import "stuff-for-page2";
```

Then in your layout you can just call

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "page1"
```

or

```
= stylesheet_link_tag "page2"
```